# How do I send strings between my osx app and arduino continuously?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, serial-port, arduino

I made a cocoa application that generates a list of instructions for an arduino uno to execute. Because the list is too large to fit at one time within the arduino's memory, I am trying to send the arduino an individual instruction at a time.

**Arduino:**

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    String in = Serial.readString();
    delay(10);
    Serial.print(in);
  }
  Serial.print("A");
}
```

**Cocoa App**

(Code after the serial port is open and working)

```
- (void)incomingTextUpdateThread: (NSThread *) parentThread {
  // mark that the thread is running
  readThreadRunning = TRUE;
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
  char byte_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // buffer for holding incoming data
  long numBytes=0; // number of bytes read during read

  // assign a high priority to this thread
  [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0];

  // this will loop unitl the serial port closes
  while(TRUE) {        
    // read() blocks until some data is available or the port is closed
   numBytes = read(serialFileDescriptor, byte_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); // read up to the size of the buffer
     if(numBytes>0) {
       if(byte_buffer[0] == 'A'){
         Coordinate *c = [coordinates objectAtIndex:coordinateIndex];
         [self writeString:[self formateCoordinateString:c]];
         coordinateIndex++;
       }
    }
    if(coordinateIndex == coordinates.count){
        close(serialFileDescriptor);
        break;
    }
  }
  readThreadRunning = FALSE;
}
```

I run the arduino code first and it prints a bunch of 'A's in the serial console. However once I start the cocoa app, it stops printing 'A's and doesn't do anything.

When I set a breakpoint within the while loop, the arduino starts printing the 'A's again. I continue to step within the while loop, and the "instruction" string is sent correctly to the arduino.

My issue is that this only works when I set this break point. Otherwise both my cocoa app and arduino app go into a stand-still.

Thanks for any and all advice! Please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: That sounds like something's buffering; may be you can "flush it" somehow after writing?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `-writeString:`? Is that writing back out to the serial port, or doing something else?